# What it Would be easier Building a Deep Net From Scratch or Using an existing Architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

In Practice with CNN what would be easier: Building a CNN from scratch or using a an existing architecture with some updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your task and the amount of data you have. If you have so much data but you can not find similar tasks to have appropriate architecture you should stack convolution and dense layers yourself. But if you have appropriate amount of data and there exist good architectures then you have to decide what you want and how is your situation. Suppose that you want to have recognition task, there are so many architectures that are applied to `ImageNet` data-set. You can use transfer learning but there is a point here. Suppose that you want to fine tune `GoogleNet`. This is a very large network and is capable for recognizing about a thousand distinct classes. If you have a recognition task with 5 classes and you have an agent that should be online, this is not logical to have such a **big** network. You may have similar performance by stacking a few layers and get better time complexity. If you don't have so much data, freezing the layers and applying transfer learning to the last layer maybe a typical solution.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you can find a network that has been trained on data remotely similar to yours, then it's a good idea to take advantage of this pre-trained network and use *fine-tuning / transfer learning* to train the model on your data.

Transfer learning occurs when we use knowledge that was gained from solving one problem and apply it to a new, but related problem.

Fine-tuning is a way of applying or utilizing transfer learning. Specifically, fine-tuning is a process that takes a model that has already been trained for a given task and then *tuning* the model to make it perform a second task. Assuming the original task is at least loosely similar to the new task, using an artificial neural network that has already been created and trained allows us to take advantage of what the model has already learned without having to develop it from scratch.

I explain the concept of fine-tuning in [this video](https://youtu.be/5T-iXNNiwIs). At 4:10, it also links to videos showing how this is process is done in code using Keras.

Comment: @StephenRauch, I further developed my answer and added explanations for the concepts I mentioned.